# PHP Error with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Below is the error which i received when running my php program.

> Notice: Undefined variable: output in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\captchahtml\AdminAddPage.php on line 147
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: output in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\captchahtml\AdminAddPage.php on line 148
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: output in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\captchahtml\AdminAddPage.php on line 156

The lines which "caused" the error is a Javascript/Jquery code as below,

```
<?php
  ...


    ...

    echo<<<ADMINADDCAPTCHA_HEAD
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Admin_Add_2.css">
    <title>Admin Main Page</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
        .....
        .....
        Line 147:  var $output = $('#output');
        Line 148:  $output.empty();
        Line 156:  $output.append(a);
        ......
        ......
            </script>

    </head>
<body>
    ...
    ...
    ?>
```

I believe php is trying to put a variable in-place of those lines. Is there a way to work sround this issue. Line 147 is 1st occurrence of "$...".
Thanks guys :)

Comment: use `var output` not `var $output`.

Comment: I think you may have some <?php tag open and not closed before using jQuery. Or a confusion between server side code and client side code

Comment: It's common practice to prefix JQuery variables with a `$` sign - however `$` also denotes the start of a variable in PHP... and since this appears to be a PHP echo (using HEREDOC syntax) that `$output` will be the (interpolated) PHP variable called `$output`. Which doesn't exist. In short, as @urfusion says - use `var output` or add a slash in front of it `var \$output`

Comment: Maybe `$('#output').val()`?

Comment: Closing your `<?php ?>` tag before you write html / javascript would probably solve this. If it's a simple `echo`, there's no point having this into PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is client side code being echo'd out from PHP using [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax and with HEREDOC syntax PHP variables can be interpolated in the output.

It's common practice to prefix JQuery variables with the `$` sign, it's the shorthand for JQuery, *however* `$` is also used by PHP to denote the start of a variable. This means that `var $output` is being picked up by the PHP interpreter and it's attempting to echo the value of the variable `$output` - which doesn't exist, hence the *undefined variable* error.

You can work around this, if you want to use a HEREDOC block, by escaping any `$` signs you want to be treated literally as `$` signs, for instance:

```
var \$output = \$('#output');
\$output.empty();
\$output.append(a);
```

Or, instead of using HEREDOC you could drop out of PHP parsing (`?> ... stuff .. <?php`) or use a [single quoted](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) string.